# Change WordPress Theme automatically for A/B test

Tags: themes

i want to switch the theme of my WP website automatically by random for my users in order to do different A/B testing actions. switch_theme is not working cause that changes the theme in the database.

But i want to do this for each user by random without changing the general themesetting in WP. Like the function WP provides when previewing a theme. How can i do that? I do not need help with the randomize function etc. I just need a hint how to switch the theme for a usersession.

A plugin is not a solution, cause there is none i could use to fulfill my requirements for the A/B test. I need to program individually for my needs.

Thanks in advance for your help!
René

Comment: You could consider reviewing/forking Rarst's [Toolbar Theme Switcher](https://github.com/Rarst/toolbar-theme-switcher) plugin for ideas or a starting point. It will allow admin users (this can be changed with a filter) to switch themes without globally making the change for all users.

Comment: I don't understand what is it that you are asking for. how to detect a session (use cookie), or how to select progrematically which theme is being used?

Comment: I would use the php session of each user to switch theme only once for a user.  Then select randomly one of my 3 themes. These 3 themes will have complete different layout and adsense placements. With this a/b test i want to test the performance of each theme.

Answer (score 0):

The way we did it was by setting up separate WordPress setups on subdomains:

- theme1.ourcompany.org
- theme2.ourcompany.org
- theme3.ourcompany.org

We used a server script cooked up by the IT Administrator to route users at random to either one of the subdomains. The difference in domain names made for a clear distinction between datasets when we compiled the analytics.

Comment: Ok, that would be a solution. But shouldn't it be possible without separate installations? I found this:  

`function custom_load_twenty_ten_template() {
    return 'twentyten';
}

function custom_load_twenty_ten_stylesheet() {
    return 'twentyten';
}

add_filter( 'template', 'custom_load_twenty_ten_template' );
add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'custom_load_twenty_ten_stylesheet' );`

but it did nothing on my site.

Comment: I found out, why it did not work. Cause this script has to be loaded via a plugin. When placing into functions.php, it is too late, cause a lot settings for rendering the WP website is already loaded. Now it works.